# segmented control to switch images in scrollview iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a view with a UINavBar in it, and a scrollview beneath that. The nav bar has a segmented button which I want to use to toggle between 2 images to be presented in the scrollview. Both of the images are in the same scrollview but one is hidden to start.

I was trying to do this like so:

```
-(IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged{
switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
{
    case 0:
        bvpiimg.hidden = NO;
        mppiimg.hidden = YES;
    case 1:
        bvpiimg.hidden = YES;
        mppiimg.hidden = NO;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

It isn't doing anything when I switch the segmented control though..
Also, these images are HUGE pngs.. Is there a better way than show/hide that would be easier on the memory/performance.

Comment: One thing to note: the iPhone doesn't officially support displaying of images greater than 1024x1024 pixels. If your images are bigger, you MUST chop them down. You may process them (e.g. cropping, scaling, whatever) even if bigger than 1024x1024 but you can't put them on screen.

Comment: It's actually an iPad app, I just wrote iPhone. The image displays and works properly in the scrollview when I run it.. I just can't get the 2 images to show/hide for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! The problem was my I had the seg control set to "touch up inside" when it needed to be "value change"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the segmented control's action is hooked up to the method in IB.

Answer (score 0):

you need a break after case 0: if this is a direct copy. also the break after case 1 isn't necessary here.